# Could a queued event interrupt an onDrawFrame call?

Tags: java, android, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

I am about to start laying foundations for game logic in my OpenGL ES 2.0 game, and I am quite concerned about handling events (mainly input events) only when I am finished rendering. I don't want the following to happen:

1. Drawing begins, some things are drawn
2. An event interrupts drawing and causes a logic update
3. Drawing continues with inconsistent logic

I still haven't found a clear answer: Yes or No. Because if this kind of code:

```
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    mGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            triangleRenderer.handleTouchPress(normalizedX, normalizedY);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

is not enough to guarantee that drawing and handling touch event are always sequential, never interleaved, then I think I would have to implement something to store and then handle "events".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing and now I'm pretty sure that events never interrupt Renderer's draw call, and are delivered in between those draw calls.

I used a 2000 x 1ms = 2s total sleep loop in onDrawFrame while logging both the moment the event reaches GLSurfaceView and the moment the Renderer's event handler is fired.

It does seem thread safe - although a bit funny: my logging code in SurfaceView, placed just before queueEvent, was always called doubly: first at the moment of touch, and then right before firing Renderer's event handler.

```
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    long tmp = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
                    Log.w("EVENT", "SurfaceView " + tmp); // executed doubly! funny stuff.
                    queueEvent(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {                              
                            gameRenderer.handleTouchPress(normalizedX, normalizedY);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: I checked what happens when you just call Renderer's method directly (without queueEvent), and it's no good. Obviously it is a method call from another thread, and it's purely asynchronous. Doesn't care about drawing in the slightest.